# Gwan : Debug option for C

Tags: debugging, handlers, g-wan

I have a signal 11 after a while with a c script in a connection handlers.

I have no memory problem and unit test work well !

I'd like to know if there is a debug mode with gwan for c scripts ? and how to activate it ?

Thanks by advance
Regards

Comment: Moreover, while a test force with siege, i find sometimes this king of error : [4287201.237795] gwan[25844]: segfault at 7f86d0b789b8 ip 00007f86d14580cc sp 00007f86d0b789b0 error 6 in libc-2.11.3.so[7f86d13b7000+159000]. Any idea ?

Comment: That's most probably a double-free *after* a few seconds all requests have been processed: GLIBC insist to call abort() in that case and other occasions (and the flags supposed to deactivate these behaviors are not reliable). Like most other servers, we have replaced the system memory allocator in G-WAN v3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they are at the core of Web development, `servlets` provide automatic crash reports (see the crash.c example).

But `connection handlers` lacked this feature introduced in G-WAN v3.6+. In this version and more recent releases, it can be enabled by a `#pragma debug` directive in the handler source code.

There's also a new and very detailled per-thread dump in v3.9+ to get a wider 'picture' of servlet/handler/libraries/server errors. It is stored in the ./trace file.

Your crash dump reports a `libc` call error. The main source of such errors has been found in memory allocations. G-WAN v3.4+ tried to catch them more effectively by using its own (wait-free) allocator.

BTW, `siege` is not performing very well whether this is on single-Cores or on multicore systems (for *performance tests*, `weighttp` will let you test the server instead of the client).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I use siege from others servers(so i am not affecting gwan server). You're talking of v3.6+ but I don't find those versions, the latest on web site is 3.3.28, isn't it ?

Comment: See http://gwan.com/faq#languages for the recent version history including betas. On another hand, public releases are presented here: http://gwan.com/en_timeline.html